# Dash Tabulator : "movableRowsConnectedTables" is not working

Tags: plotly-dash, tabulator

I’m trying to use the "movableRowsConnectedTables" built-in functionality as [explained in the tabulator.js examples](https://tabulator.info/examples/5.4#movable-between-tables)

It doesn’t seem to work as expected:

```
import dash
from dash import html
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import dash_tabulator

columns = [
    { "title": "Name",
     "field": "name",}
    ]

options_from = {
    'movableRows' : True,
    'movableRowsConnectedTables':"tabulator_to",
    'movableRowsReceiver': "add",
    'movableRowsSender': "delete",
    'height':200,
    'placeholder':'No more Rows'
           }
options_to = {
    'movableRows' : True,
    'height':200,
    'placeholder':'Drag Here'
    }

data = [
    {"id":1, "name":"a"},
    {"id":2, "name":"b"},
    {"id":3, "name":"c"},
]


layout = html.Div(
    [
        dbc.Row(
            [
                dbc.Col(
                    [   html.Header('DRAG FROM HERE'),
                        dash_tabulator.DashTabulator(
                            id='tabulator_from',
                            columns=columns,
                            options=options_from,
                            data=data,
                            ),
                        ], width = 6
                    ),
                dbc.Col(
                    [   html.Header('DROP HERE'),
                        dash_tabulator.DashTabulator(
                            id='tabulator_to',
                            columns=columns,
                            options=options_to,
                            data = []
                            ),
                        ], width = 6
                    )
                ]
            )      
        ]
    )

app = dash.Dash(external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP])

app.layout = dbc.Container(layout, fluid=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Is it also possible to get callbacks when elements were dropped?

It would be great to have this functionality inside dash!
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FT4z4.jpg)

Comment: Where is your callback? How didn't the callback work as intended?

Comment: Hi Hamzah, I wasn't clear indeed. 
I mentioned the callback as an extra question. The prime question is how to get the 'movableRowsConnectedTables' option to work in dash-tabulator (native client side).
 
Once we've got this working on the client side, we'll have to start thinking about how to get the dragdrop-info back to python. Hence the secondary question about the callback

Answer (score 0):

im not familiar with tabulator_dash but the table your sending too also needs a 'movableRowsConnectedTables':"tabulator_from" option

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).